# HTML : Why does a button element always appear slightly below the other elements?

Tags: html, button

I have noticed that the  `<button>` element in HTML always appears slightly lower than other elements as shown in the figure below.

[image]

As you can see, the "Go" button is slightly lower than the textarea element which on the same row as it is. The code for this is as follows...

```
<table width="100%">
            <tr>
                <th rowspan="2" align="left">
                    <img width="120px" height="60px" src="test-image.jpg" />
                </th>
                <th align="right">
                    User &nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <a href="">My Garage</a> &nbsp;|&nbsp;
                    <a href="">Account Settings</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;
                    <a href="">Sign Out</a> &nbsp;|&nbsp;
                    <br/>
                    <textarea rows="1" id="search_text"></textarea><button>Go!</button>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Why does this happen and what is the easiest fix for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try applying `vertical-align: text-bottom;` to your button.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using an `input` tag, not a `textarea` for a single row.  Try this code:

```
<input type="text" id="search_text"><button>Go!</button>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```